# CSS/JS - How to override parents transition in 1 child but not the others

Tags: javascript, css

## HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <img class='child' src="https://picsum.photos/200/400?random=1" alt="">
    <img class='child' src="https://picsum.photos/200/400?random=2" alt="">
    <img class='child special-child' src="https://picsum.photos/200/400?random=3" alt="">
    <img class='child' src="https://picsum.photos/200/400?random=4" alt="">
    <img class='child' src="https://picsum.photos/200/400?random=5" alt="">
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.parent {
    transition: transform 250ms ease-in;
}
```

So now all child classes will have that transition effect for transform, but for special-child (who will be a different image every time and will be selected with JS not the css, I just put the class in the html to explain) I want the transition to work different and in parts, I want to do 2-3 transitions on it that together will take up the 250ms the others have and I want to do it at the same time as the others are moving (I want all transform to go happen at the same time) they are all being called on a click with an eventListener.

The problem is I can't override the transform on the parent because its needed for the other child's, and if I add a transition property to the child it doesnt do anything (since its there for tranforms on its child).

So how could I give the 'special-child' the transition properties I want???

Thanks

Comment: You can do this with `:nth` selector in css like `.parent img:nth-child(1){}`

Comment: This will put the property on the child, I need to change the transition property within the parent just only for that child.

Comment: Then David solution below works

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the transition rule in the `.parent` (so its children inherit it), you can apply the desired transition directly to all `.child` elements **except** the "special" one:

```
.child:not(.special-child) { ... }
```

And then, make the correct rules for that element.

```js
document.getElementById('transform').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var children = document.querySelectorAll('.child');
  children.forEach(function(child) {
    child.classList.add('transformed');
  });
});
```

```css
.child:not(.special-child) {
  transition: transform 2s;
}
.transformed:not(.special-child) {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.special-child {
  transition: width 0.5s, height 0.5s 0.5s, transform 1s 1s;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.special-child.transformed {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img class='child' src="https://picsum.photos/100/100?random=1" alt="">
  <img class='child special-child' src="https://picsum.photos/100/100?random=2" alt="">
  <img class='child' src="https://picsum.photos/100/100?random=3" alt="">
</div>

<button id="transform">Click me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set transform on .child

```css
.child {
  transition: transform 2s;
}
.child.transformed {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.special-child {
  transition: width 0.5s, height 0.5s, transform 1s;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.special-child.transformed {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  transform: translateY(200px);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img class='child' src="https://picsum.photos/100/100?random=1" alt="">
  <img class='child special-child' src="https://picsum.photos/100/100?random=2" alt="">
  <img class='child' src="https://picsum.photos/100/100?random=3" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. New answers are expected to add something, well, new. You just copied the code from my answer and, actually, didn't do it right. The OP wants all animations starting and finishing at the same time. Without the delays, that won't happen. Also, even when overriding the rules works correctly, setting  explicitly `.child:not(.special-child) { ... }` shows the OP the possibility to don't set rules for specific elements inside a group of them.